How to parameterize pipeline concurrency (number of parallel runs) in Azure Data Factory
I have two pipelines:
parent pipeline to read configuration file (lookup activity), filter it with filter activity and pass the resulting array (e.g. 50 items) to ForEach activity to run child pipeline to perform per-item work in a predefined number of parallel runs (e.g. 3 at once).
The child pipeline is executing its tasks using SQL servers,
and different servers have different number of session allowed to run in parallel for this solution, e.g.

1 session for SQLsrv1
3 sessions for SQLsrv2
5 sessions for SQLsrv3

so I need to somehow parameterize that number of parallel runs for the child pipeline, but:

It could be done using child pipeline's concurrency parameter if I had only 1 SQL server,
but what to do with many if pipeline's concurrency parameter does not accept dynamic content?
ForEach activity does not allow to parameterize its batch count either

Should I opt to:

creating 3rd pipeline for offloading just ForEach activity to it,
then clone this 3rd pipeline to have e.g. 5 pipelines with different number of parallel runs in ForEach activity (1...5)
adding switch activity to parent pipeline to have e.g. 5 branches for 1...5 parallels and add ExecutePipeline activity to trigger one of those '3rd' pipelines clones?

Is there a better/simpler solution?
Thanks!

For executing for-each activity for different size of batches, you can define the configuration or lookup table like below.



Batch
Table_name




1
table1


1
table2


2
table3


2
table4


2
table5



Here, table1 and table2 needs to be executed parallelly. Similarly, table3, table4, table5 need to be executed parallelly. These two batches have different size to run. In order to do this, you can follow the below approach. Two pipelines- One for grouping the batches and other for executing them in batches.

Pipeline 1 is considered as the outer pipeline. In that Lookup activity is used to select only batch field data. Batch value will be passed as a parameter to child pipeline sequentially.

Query in lookup activity: select distinct batch from config_table


For each activity is added after the lookup activity. Sequential is checked and in items text box, output of lookup activity is given @activity('Lookup1').output.value.

Another pipeline pipeline2 is created with the parameter param_batch and it is considered as the inner pipeline for pipeline 1

In pipeline 1, inside for-each activity, execute pipeline activity is added. pipeline2 is added in the invoked pipeline. Value for the parameter param_batch is given as @{item().batch}


In pipeline2, Lookup activity is added with dataset referring the same config table. Query to be given in lookup activty: `select * from config_table where batch= @{pipeline().parameters.param_batch}

Next to lookup activity, for-each activity is added and in items text box, lookup activty output value is given. Sequential is not checked here. This would help in running all the tables in that batch run together.


